# Unable to show UILabel after add it to subview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var testview: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
   
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemGray.cgColor
        testview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        testview.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        testview.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        
        testview.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: testview.bounds).cgPath
        
        testview.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        testview.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        
        testview.addSubview(result)
    }
```

After I add `result` to `testview` as a subview it's disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your Storyboard already added `result` into the view hierarchy so when you add it again the frame stays the same but the point of reference changes since the superview is now `testView` so in your case it's going beyond the visible bounds. If you want the `UILabel` to be a subview of the `testView` I'd recommend making that change directly on the Storyboard, creating the UILabel programmatically instead of using Storyboards/IBOutlets or updating the frame of the label after adding it to `testView`.